# stop the trigger

Tags: trigger

Trigger is worked First time only if it updating the Record  for second time it should be stopped ,because status have only one picklist value called activated, if you second time gets edited another New Record is Created, how to Avoid it

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    for(Order ce:trigger.new) {

        if(ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```

Comment: Check if there are any child `Order_Pricebook__c` records for the current `Order`, if there's no then perform your logic. else don't

Comment: share the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you can use code similar to one below:

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    for(Order ce:trigger.new) {

        if(trigger.oldmap.get(ce.id).status!='Activated' && ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```

If condition given above checks if status field value was modified to 'Activated' from some other value. This condition will only come once based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for the logic that I've explain in the comment. Make sure you do have proper API names for the relationships (Order_Pricebooks__r). Better get them from your WSDL.

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
    for(Order o : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Order_Pricebooks__r) FROM Order WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]){
        // if there are no any child records, collect ids
        if(o.Order_Pricebooks__r.isEmpty()){
            orderList.add(o);
        }
    }

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    //  iterate over collected records and create child records
    for(Order ce:orderList) {

        if(ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```